# JNI - How to convert jshortArray to short *

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

> I have a **dll file** that contains
>   the following function:
>
> ```
> unsigned char * EncodingData(short Data[], int Length);
> ```
>
> I want to call this **native method**
>   in java. So I have created one
>   **wrapper dll** that contains the follwing function corresponding to the
>   above function
>
> ```
> JNIEXPORT jcharArray JNICALL Java_com_common_FilterWrapper_EncodingData (JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jshortArray shortData, jint len)
> ```
>
> Now I am calling the above **JNI
>   function** from java and it is being
>   called successfully.

**Problem:**

I want to call the **dll file's function** from **wrapper dll's function** but I don't know how to convert the following:

- **jshortArray** to **short []** (to pass the data to the **dll file's function** which is expecting **short []** and not **jshortArray**)
- **unsigned char** to **jcharArray** (to return the value back to the java function)

**Note: The wrapper dll is written in VC++**

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned short tempElem;
jshort* test = env->GetShortArrayElements(shortData, NULL);
int size = (sizeof(test) / sizeof(*test)) - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    tempElem = (unsigned short)test[i]);
    printf("[%d] test %u  || size = %d\n", i, tempElem, size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use env->GetShortArrayElements, for example if your jshortArray is called sdata_jshort, your short* pointer is called short_data_c_pointer, then

short_data_c_pointer = env->GetFloatArrayElements(sdata_jshort, 0);

Answer (score -1):

This is covered in the [JNI documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#array_operations).

To summarize:

> First, we provide a set of functions
>   to copy primitive array elements
>   between a segment of a Java array and
>   a native memory buffer. Use these
>   functions if a native method needs
>   access to only a small number of
>   elements in a large array.
>
> Second, programmers can use another
>   set of functions to retrieve a
>   pinned-down version of array elements.
>   Keep in mind that these functions may
>   require the Java VM to perform storage
>   allocation and copying. Whether these
>   functions in fact copy the array
>   depends on the VM implementation