# C++ to java array conversions

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

How can i convert a short* from c++ to a jshortArray from java?

I'm looking for some documentation online, but it's not easy to find.

Comment: You are trying to achieve this via JNI, correct?

Comment: [Link][1] this is reverse of what you want but it might be helpul.


  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586155/jni-how-to-convert-jshortarray-to-short

Comment: @Vulcan yes! I'm writing a jni cpp code!

Comment: @ÖvünçMetin I know the reverse. But is not the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jshortArray convertShortArrayToJNI(JNIEnv* env, short* arr, size_t count) {
  jshortArray retval = env->NewShortArray(count);
  env->SetShortArrayRegion(retval,0,count,arr);
  return retval;
}
```

You don't need to free the `retval`. It is a "local reference", which means that it will be freed by JVM as soon as you return through JNI from the recent call. Unless you are calling it from a native thread, of course...

Comment: `arr` is competely specific to your implementation and the memory management of it is up to you. I don't know, and JVM can't know, whether it is a pointer to RAII construct (and as a such will be freed automatically) or you created it manually and need to remember deallocating it.

Comment: I used your code and the following error is showed: `ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)`. I'm freeing the created array (it's not returned, only used in a callback function) with `jenv->ReleaseShortArrayElements(retval, arr, 0);`. There is something wrong?